# how to make sbt portable?

Tags: scala, sbt

what I wanted to do is to make the sbt portable, at least portable among different Windows machines, so that my sbt plugins, settings, ivy repo, etc. don't have to be setup again on every computer.

my approach is to put the `sbt.bat`, `sbt-launcher.jar` and all its required directories, like `.sbt`, `plugins` and `.ivy` into a folder to be synced by Dropbox or likes

---

I have successfully changed the boot/ivy directory by using `-Dsbt.boot.directory` `-Dsbt.ivy.hom` in command line for sbt-launch.jar, but I can't find the same for `plugins` or the whole `.sbt` folder.

---

finally I tried Sandro's solution, so far it seems working~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://code.google.com/p/symlinker/ to create a Symbolic link to the .sbt folder in your Dropbox directory. That way, Dropbox will see the .sbt folder inside its own directory, while the "actual" folder will still be in the default location.

Comment: not the type of answer I expected, but it do solve the problem~~ thanks for such a simple solution~~